Wordpress admin panel stopped working in cloudflare
I moved a wordpress site over to Cloudflare by moving DNS config there, and used free tier.
Everything works fine, but now the /wp-admin admin panel has stopped working. I get redirected to $domain/wp-admin which is weird, since the config worked before.
$ http -v get https://example.com/wp-admin
GET /wp-admin HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: example.com
User-Agent: HTTPie/3.2.3



HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
CF-RAY: 8fa817bda9c79079-FRA
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Tue, 31 Dec 2024 06:08:02 GMT
Location: http://$domain/wp-admin/

Anybody know what is the issue? In Apache config I remember there are variables like $domain, but how could that have stopped working because of nameservers?

Okay I got a tip from r/cloudflare that if you enable Strict SSL, it would work. And it did. No idea why, but posting here if someone has the same problem.

WordPress requires you to use SSL to access the admin. Without Strict SSL enabled, Cloudflare was proxying your admin page requests to WordPress without using an SSL connection between Cloudflare and your WordPress server. WordPress saw this (correctly) as insecure, and tried to redirect you to force you to use SSL, but that doesn't work if Cloudflare isn't configured to connect to the origin server over SSL (Strict SSL setting).
